# #if defined(token) && token == ... - is this syntax legal?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

assuming I have such code:

```
#if defined(SOMEDEF) && SOMEDEF >= 5
  // ...
#endif
```

Basically, `SOMEDEF` may not be defined but used in suppressed branch of operator `&&`. GCC accepts this code, but is it legal according to standard? Do all compilers support this?

Comment: for instance, `#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute) && __has_cpp_attribute(deprecated)` doesn't work

Comment: It is working on all the compilers I tried at godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/U43E2o

Comment: The code in your comment is substantially different to the code in your question. If you really mean to ask about the code in the comment then please actually use that code for your question

Comment: @M.M, comment was intended to extend question, not to override it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly, it depends.

```
#if defined(SOMEDEF) && SOMEDEF >= 5
```

Is legal if one of the following is true:

- `SOMEDEF` is defined, *and* the macro expansion of `SOMEDEF` is such that the above is a valid expression.
- `SOMEDEF` is *not* defined.  In this case, `SOMEDEF >= 5` is still a valid expression.  Note that after macro replacement (and `defined` operator evaluation), any identifiers (except `true`/`false`) that are not defined are replaced with `0`; `0 >= 5` is a valid subexpression.

For example, this is *not* valid:

```
#define SOMEDEF 0(0)
#if defined(SOMEDEF) && SOMEDEF >= 5
```

...because `0(0) >= 5` is not a valid subexpression.

> for instance, `#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute) && __has_cpp_attribute(deprecated)` doesn't work

You mean to say, this doesn't work when `__has_cpp_attribute` is not defined.  The same thing happens in this case; `0(0)` is not a valid subexpression.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the code you have in your question is valid. In fact, you don't even need to check if `SOMEDEF` is defined. It will be assumed to be 0 if it isn't. So, this is functionally equivalent:

```
#if SOMEDEF >= 5
  // ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this syntax is totally valid. Here if `SOMEDEF` defined than only `SOMEDEF >= 5` will going to be expanded else block will be not expanded.